# What could be alternative for hashmap as it's consuming more memory

Tags: java, memory-management, hashmap, out-of-memory

I am using hashmap in my application at various places. Especially while executing jobs, it's consuming more memory resulting in server shutdown. what could be the replacement of hashmap in spring-boot application.

Comment: Please show us a [mre]. What are you putting into the HashMap?

Comment: I'm thinking ... a database.

Answer (score 1):

Hashmap itself is very standard and there isn't a more memory efficient replacement that is equivalent in general. You'll need to change how you are using it. You haven't provided enough information to diagnose the issue but my first guess would be that you might be storing things in maps which make them "reachable" after they are needed, thus preventing the Garbage Collector from freeing up the memory?